# Cassandra : can't assign requested address at

Tags: cassandra

I have datastax-cassandra 1.2.5 and I have following settings in .yaml file

- storage_port: 7000
- ssl_storage_port: 7001
- listen_address: localhost
- rpc_port: 9160

I keep getting this. I tried to change the storage port once and it worked but than after same thing. I am not able to restart cassandra again

```
    INFO 16:33:02,714 Completed flushing /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/local/system-local-ic-17-Data.db (241 bytes) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1371684781848, position=50142)
ERROR 16:33:02,793 Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessagingService.getServerSocket(MessagingService.java:446)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessagingService.listen(MessagingService.java:389)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.joinTokenRing(StorageService.java:583)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:548)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:445)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:325)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:413)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:456)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:344)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:336)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:199)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:67)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessagingService.getServerSocket(MessagingService.java:436)
    ... 7 more
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessagingService.getServerSocket(MessagingService.java:446)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessagingService.listen(MessagingService.java:389)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.joinTokenRing(StorageService.java:583)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:548)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:445)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:325)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:413)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:456)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:344)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:336)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:199)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:67)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessagingService.getServerSocket(MessagingService.java:436)
    ... 7 more
Exception encountered during startup: java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address
ERROR 16:33:02,798 Exception in thread Thread[StorageServiceShutdownHook,5,main]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.stopRPCServer(StorageService.java:321)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.shutdownClientServers(StorageService.java:362)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.access$000(StorageService.java:88)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService$1.runMayThrow(StorageService.java:513)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: What is your seeds list / cluster architecture?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most likely there's something wrong with network configuration: `localhost` resolves either to invalid hostname assigned by DHCP (something like `192-168-1-10.local`) or to local IPv6 address (`::1`) and IPv6 is disabled in java.

- Check `/etc/hosts`
- Check output of `hostname` command
- Try setting `listen_address` to `127.0.0.1` or to valid IP address.
- Check `rpc_address` setting in `cassandra.yaml`. Try setting it to `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Thanks Wildfire, after changing listen_address from localaddress to my local ip address, the issue got resolved.

Comment: Setting both `listen_address` and `rpc_address` to `127.0.0.1` worked for me!

Comment: This exact issue happened to me. Running a VM and then switched VM from ethernet to wifi which changed my network settings. Checked hosts file and was set to 127.0.0.1. However when I pinged my localhost from my VM, I got 192.x.x.x. So it wasn't resolving properly. I then set to 127.0.0.1 last stated above and voila!